# derivative of the Euclidean norm of matrix and matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces

I have two matrices 
$A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
3&7&9&1\\
4&1&2&3\\
5&6&3&7\\
2&4&3&7
\end{array}} \right]$
and
$B = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
L^3/T^2&0&0&0\\
0&L^3/T^2&0&0\\
0&0&L/T&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{array}} \right]$.

A is the Frechet derivative matrix. The reason of the B shaping like this is because I am trying to implement non-integer units to time and length.

I am trying to improve the condition number of a matrix A by right product matrix A with matrix B. Therefore, I need to minimize the condition number of AB.

Obviously, condition number of A is a product of norm(AB)*norm((AB)^(-1)).

Therefore, to optimize the condition number of AB with best T and L, I need to get the derivative of norm(AB).

how do I find derivative of norm(AB)?

The Euclidean norm of A is ${\rm{norm}}(A) = \sqrt {{\sigma _{\max }}({A^*}A)} $, $\sigma$ is the eigenvalue, and $A^*$ is the transpose of A.

the Euclidean norm is defined on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could format your question properly, as is explained in [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360)

Comment: I am new to this. Is the revised question OK?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the gradient of a condition number based on the Euclidean norm. Since I don't know how to do that, here is the gradient based on a Frobenius norm.

Define the scalars
$$\eqalign{
 \alpha^2 &= \|X\|_F^2 &= X:X \cr
 \beta^2 &= \|X^{-1}\|_F^2 &= X^{-1}:X^{-1} \cr
 \phi &= {\alpha}{\beta} \cr
}$$
where $\phi$ is the condition number in terms of the Frobenius norm.
$$\eqalign{
d\alpha &= \alpha^{-1}X:dX \cr
d\beta &= -\beta^{-1}(X^TXX^T)^{-1}:dX \cr
}$$
Now we're ready to start differentiating
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= \beta\,d\alpha + \alpha\,d\beta \cr
&= \Big(\beta\alpha^{-1}X - \alpha\beta^{-1}(X^TXX^T)^{-1}\Big):dX \cr
}$$
In your problem, $X=AB$ and we are interested in finding the gradient wrt $B$.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
&= \Big(\beta\alpha^{-1}X - \alpha\beta^{-1}(X^TXX^T)^{-1}\Big):A\,dB \cr
&= \Big(\beta\alpha^{-1}A^TX - \alpha\beta^{-1}A^T(X^TXX^T)^{-1}\Big):dB \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial B}
&= \beta\alpha^{-1}A^TX - \alpha\beta^{-1}A^T(X^TXX^T)^{-1} \cr
&= \beta\alpha^{-1}A^TAB - \alpha\beta^{-1}A^T(B^TA^TABB^TA^T)^{-1} \cr
&= \beta\alpha^{-1}A^TAB - \alpha\beta^{-1}(B^TA^TABB^T)^{-1} \cr
\cr
}$$
**NB:**  In some of the steps above, a colon was used as a convenient product notation for the trace function, i.e. 
$$P:Q = {\rm Tr}(P^TQ)$$